# Power BI Embed set parameter request not working

Tags: parameter-passing, powerbi

I am sending post request to set parameter value, but unable to figure out what to write in Data field of the request. I am currently sending the request as follows

```
dest = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/' + self.group_id \
           + '/datasets/' + self.dataset_id + '/UpdateParameters'

    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.access_token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset = utf-8'}
    param = { "name": "PlanningSession", "newValue": "28" }
    set_param = requests.post(dest, data=param, headers=headers)
```

It is giving me error as:

```
{'error': {'code': 'BadRequest',
  'details': [{'message': "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: n. Path '', line 0, position 0.",
    'target': 'updateDatasetParametersRequest'}],
  'message': 'Bad Request'}}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. You could probably write **anything** in that field, but it's another question whether that makes sense

Comment: Yeah right, Let me show you what  i am currently sending
data =  { 
  "updateDetails": [ 
    { 
      "name": "MaxId", 
      "newValue": "5678" 
    }
  ] 
}

Comment: It is returning me this error {'error': {'code': '', 'message': 'An error has occurred.'}} @Nico Haase

Comment: Please add such stuff to the question and see whether you can enable a more verbose error level on that server

Comment: is it possible for you to show some working example using Set parameter via api call

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the doc:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt845781.aspx

It looks like you're missing the correct structure for the request body.
From the example given there, it requires an `"updateDetails"` array, in which you'd put your new params.

Also, please note that the API and its params are case-sensitive.

From the example in the doc:

```json
{ 
  "updateDetails": [ 
    { 
      "name": "MaxId", 
      "newValue": "5678" 
    }, 
    { 
      "name": "StrParam", 
      "newValue": "Another Hello" 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

Comment: Can you try and attach the response headers and\or body?

Comment: Hi I have tried this approach as well  { "updateDetails": [ { "name": "MaxId", "newValue": "5678" } ] } but error it is giving to me is {'error': {'code': '', 'message': 'An error has occurred.'}} @RBreuer

Comment: Response Code = 500, headers = {'Cache-Control': 'no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata.metadata=minimal', 'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains', 'X-Frame-Options': 'deny', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'RequestId': 'facd30cf-7eb2-4240-97ba-e30d4c101b9c', 'OData-Version': '4.0', 'Date': 'Mon, 26 Mar 2018 07:16:28 GMT'} ,  reason  = Internal Server Error @RBreuer

Comment: This might be a shot in the dark, but did you actually send the example and not your values?

try sending { "updateDetails":[{ "name": "PlanningSession", "newValue": "28" }] }

Comment: Check to see if your encoding of the JSON is correct, i.e. if there are no unnecessary characters in between, like the quotes or \r\n...

it looks like a parsing issue, since if there was a problem with the key or value you'd get a different error, stating NotFound or BadRequest